# React: redux-axios: How to access the state of one component accessible to another component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-router, react-router-dom

My question is a bit different from other ones on stack-overflow because I already am using Redux, and my problem is that the data is not loaded properly. Let me explain:

I have two components `Bookings` and `Rooms`, and it is present in my `Routes`:

```
class Routes extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Switch>
        <Route path='/' exact component={Bookings} />
        <Route path='/bookings' component={Bookings} />
        <Route path='/rooms' component={Rooms} />
      </Switch>
    );
  }
}
```

Simplified version of `Bookings`:

```
class Bookings extends React.Component {

    componentDidMount(){
        this.props.load(services['bookings']);
    }

    render() {    

        const bookingsList = this.props.bookings.map(booking => <p>Booking ID: {booking.id} Booking: {booking.name} Room ID: {booking.room_id}</p>)
        return <>
                    <p>Bookings are</p>
                    {bookingsList}
                </>
    }

}

function mapStateToProps(storeState){
    let bookings = storeState.bookingsState;
    return { bookings : bookings };
}

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch){
    let actionDispatchers = bindActionCreators(actionCreators, dispatch);
    return actionDispatchers;
}

export default connect(
    mapStateToProps,
    mapDispatchToProps
)(Bookings);
```

`Rooms`:

```
class Rooms extends React.Component {

    componentDidMount(){
        this.props.load(services['rooms']);
    }

    render() {    

        const roomsList = this.props.rooms.map(room => <p>Room ID: {room.id} Name: {room.name}</p>)
        return <>
                    <p>Rooms are:</p>
                    {roomsList}
                </>
    }

}

function mapStateToProps(storeState){
    let rooms = storeState.roomsState;
    return { rooms : rooms };
}

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch){
    let actionDispatchers = bindActionCreators(actionCreators, dispatch);
    return actionDispatchers;
}

export default connect(
    mapStateToProps,
    mapDispatchToProps
)(Rooms);
```

Each of the components were working very well independently. I wanted to use `roomsState` inside `Bookings` to resolve Room IDs to Room Names. So I added `roomsState` in `mapStateToProps`:

```
function mapStateToProps(storeState){
    let bookings = storeState.bookingsState;
    let rooms = storeState.roomsState;
    return { bookings : bookings, rooms: rooms };
}
```

But the problem here, I am guessing is that data is not loaded into `roomState` till the user navigates to the `Rooms` component:

[image]

How should I solve it the proper react-redux way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Call your `load` action in your `Routes` component and pass it down to your `Bookings` like this:

```
class Routes extends React.Component {
  componentDidMount(){
        this.props.load(services['rooms']);
    }

  render() {
    return (
      <Switch>
        <Route 
          path='/' 
          render={(props) => <Bookings {...props} rooms={this.props.rooms} />}
        />

        <Route 
          path='/bookings' 
          render={(props) => <Bookings {...props} rooms={this.props.rooms} />}
        />
        <Route 
          path='/rooms' 
          render={(props) => <Rooms {...props} isAuthed={true} />}
        />
      </Switch>
    );
  }
}

function mapStateToProps(storeState){
  let rooms = storeState.roomsState;
  let bookings = storeState.bookingsState;
    return { rooms : rooms, bookings: bookings };
}

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch){
    let actionDispatchers = bindActionCreators(actionCreators, dispatch);
    return actionDispatchers;
}

export default connect(
    mapStateToProps,
    mapDispatchToProps
)(Routes);
```